# Filter in AngularJS converted to VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I used AngularJS for a long time and now I'm making the switch to VueJS, but I can't figure out why this simple Angular code isn't easily converted to in VueJS.

This is a search-field:
`<input type="search" ng-model="searchFor.$">`

And then I'm using it like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter: search">
        {{ user.email }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

This filter is an easy thing and search in *everything* in the 'users'-array, so not even the mailaddresses.

How can I do this easily in Vue? Can't figure it out, only can find solutions where you define the specific column it should look.

Comment: You can user a methods that riceve your data and filter it, or you can procede with a computed method that's do the same thing. take a look at this (codepen)[https://codepen.io/KalidouDiagne/pen/NLVdGp?editors=1111]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you must use a computed property that returns a filtred array. The computed array will recursively search in each string properties of your user.

Here is an example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      search : '',
      users : [{name : "John Doe", email : "xerox@hotmail.us"}, {name : "Jane Doe"}],
    }
  },
  computed : {
    filteredUsers() {
      if (!this.search) return this.users
      
      var find =  function(object, search) {
        for (var property in object) {
          if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (typeof object[property] == "object"){
              find(object[property]);
            } else if (object[property].includes !== undefined){
              if (object[property].includes(search)) return true;
            }
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
      
      return this.users.filter(user => {
        return find(user, this.search)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Filter users">
  <p v-show="!filteredUsers.length">No results</p>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user in filteredUsers">{{user.name}}, email : {{user.email || 'N/A'}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: great thanks, I used a Computed already.. How to re-add this?  This did I use: 
orderedList: function () {
                return _.orderBy(this.users, 'name')
            },

Comment: And this doesn't work when the User arrays has a Object inside

Comment: how to extend this with a "_.orderBy(this.users, 'name') " function to the list? it works only when it's an array with items, not when item has objects inside @5883759